# Simple random walk in the limit

Tags: random-walk

Consider simple random walk: $X_n=\pm1$ with equal probabilities. $S_n =\sum_{i=1}^nX_i$. For finite $n$ we can write

$$S_n=\sum_{i=1}^nX_i=\sum_{i=1}^nX_i^+ -\sum_{i=1}^nX_i^-$$
So that
$$E[S_n]=\sum_{i=1}^nE[X_i^+] -\sum_{i=1}^nE[X_i^-]$$

However, $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\sum_{i=1}^nE[X_i^+]=\infty$ and $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\sum_{i=1}^nE[X_i^-]=\infty$.

So, what happens to $E[S_n]$ in the limit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply we have $$E(S_n) = E(\sum_{i=1}^n X_i) =\sum_{i=1}^n E( X_i) = \sum_{i=1}^n 0 = 0$$
so $\lim_{n\to\infty}E(S_n) = \lim_{n\to\infty} 0 = 0$

Comment: You are using linearity of expectations. Actually, my question is if it holds in the limit in this case?

Comment: @d.k.o. If all $ES_n$ are $0$, then its limit is still zero. what you asks for is $\lim E(S_n)$, not $E(\lim S_n)$

Comment: OK. So, are $\lim E(S_n)$ and $E(\lim S_n)$ equal in this case?
I mean, Fubini does not help here because $\sum_{n=1}^\infty E[|X_n|]=\infty$

Comment: @d.k.o. $\lim S_n$ does not exist, we can only say $\limsup_n S_n = +\infty$ and $\liminf_n S_n = -\infty$

Comment: Thank's. It seems trivial, but I was looking for a formal justification...

Comment: @d.k.o. for a formal justification, maybe you can look at [this](http://www.statslab.cam.ac.uk/~james/Markov/s16.pdf)